# to redirect non-existing subdomain to a rewritten existing url using part of the subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried this with .htaccess but was getting error searched the internet but could not get it.

When a non existing subdomain (like subname.domain.com) is entered into the address bar, i want it to redirects to something like domain.com/subname which would be checked through php routing script if the uri exists. I have developed the php routing script which works well.

Please how do I achieve this, i know mod-rewrite with .htaccess is all I need, and i already have a .htaccess file which works for redirecting to index.php tested on localhost server (xampp) containing the following

But please what do I need to add to the code below to make non-existing subdomain link like subname.domain.com redirect to domain.com/subname Please note that the subname used in the subdomain is needed in the redirect uri as written above

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitefolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.png|\.jpg|\.PNG|\.JPG|\.gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(uploads)  - [L]
RewriteRule ^(uploads/*)  - [L]

</IfModule>
```

Please, any help will be appreciated, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

There is something called

### _wildcard_domain

record in the DNS zone. You can refer this wiki link for more details :

[WildCard DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)

However If you will have that option of setting that wildcard domain name server depends upon Domain service provider.